# How to convert dart:ffi Char to String

Tags: c, dart, dart-ffi

I have a `dart:ffi` Struct that contains a pointer to a Char and int len

```dart
class UnnamedStruct1 extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> ptr;

  @ffi.Int()
  external int len;
}
```

it is supposed to represent a `String` (later to parse as Uri)
how do I convert it to a string

Comment: How is the `C` tag relevant?

Comment: that's what I'm binding; the whole point of dart:ffi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a function to convert the UnnamedStruct1 instance to a Dart String

```
String unnamedStruct1ToString(UnnamedStruct1 struct) {
  // Cast the pointer to a Pointer<Uint8>
  ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> uint8Pointer = struct.ptr.cast<ffi.Uint8>();

  // Create a Dart String from the Utf8 encoded data
  String result = ffi.Utf8.fromUtf8(uint8Pointer, struct.len);

  return result;
}


void main() {
  // Assuming you have an instance of UnnamedStruct1 called myStruct
  UnnamedStruct1 myStruct = // ... initialize your struct here

  // Convert the struct to a Dart String
  String myString = unnamedStruct1ToString(myStruct);

  // Print the resulting string
  print(myString);
}
```

This should do it

Answer (score 1):

the method `fromUtf8` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929092/9836706) by @mozzarella is deprecated
and the `cast()` target the wrong Type (should be Utf8, not Uint8)
but overall (hopefully) pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

I'll wait before accepting anything as there is a chance that
`.cast<Utf8>()` will blow up

```dart
class UnnamedStruct1 extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> ptr;

  @ffi.Int()
  external int len;
}


final UnnamedStruct1 struct = //...
final string = struct.ptr
        .cast<Utf8>()
        .toDartString(length: struct.ref.uri.len);
```